# Symfony Twig customize error page leads to error

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, twig

I am using Symfony 2.7.4 and I want to create custom error page for 404 code.
I created file

> /Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/404.html.twig

as it is described on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#use-default-exception-controller

But if I enter nonexisting URL it leads to the error 500 internal server error (without 404.html.twig it leads to 404 not found error with default look). How to fix it?

Comment: There is probably an error in the code of your custom error page.

Comment: My custom page looks like "<h1>error</h1>" and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all the cookbook shows the tree**:

```
app/
└─ Resources/
   └─ TwigBundle/
      └─ views/
         └─ Exception/
            ├─ error404.html.twig
```

You've got a '404.html.twig', so should falling back to the generic errors templates.

**Go into a debug mode and inspect details of server error.**

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late, but your problem is related to `404.html.twig` file source.

The example of `404.html.twig` page at  http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#use-default-exception-controller has line `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}`.
This line makes all your problems. Remove it and your custom 404 will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This command helped me after overriding twig bundle error templates:

If you add a template in a new location, you may need to clear your cache, even if you are in debug mode:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#templates
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-error-templates